# Generating a Pareto chart based on date

Tags: excel, vba, pareto-chart

I would like to make a Pareto chart based on 2 columns of Data. 1 is a string of letters and numbers let's call it column A, the other is a date (formatted as dd-mmm-yy e.g. 18-Oct-2017).

There is no option to create a Pareto chart in Excel 2010 (the version I'm using), and I was wondering if it's possible to create a Pareto chart with those data.

Basically I want it to display, based on year, how many entries there are in Column A. For example, if there are 4 entries in Column A associated with 2014, I want 2014 on the X-axis and the 4 on the Y-axis to show in the chart.

I'm new to vba coding so I would really appreciate any help I can get in this. I have already tried to google it but there isn't anything that could help. If you have sample code that would be really nice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the distinct months, apply simple excel formulaes to create 2 columns (one for the bar data and one for the line data) and create a combo chart with that data with one of the series as a line